# Mac Air (2015) keeps shutting off immediately after being unplugged from charger

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

My air which is 4 years old now keeps shutting off immediately if it gets disconnected from the charger. It won't even turn on if it's not plugged in. It started happening about a month ago randomly, but not consistently. At the beginning sometimes it would shut down when the battery was only at 80%. Now even though it says 100% if the charger accidentally gets pulled out it'll just turn off.

I've tried resetting the SMC a few times but it didn't seem to do anything. I don't think I have the right screwdrivers to try to actually take the battery out myself.

I copied the battery info below and attached a screenshot of the coconut battery.

Does this mean I need to replace it? It's about $130 on Apple's website to get a new one. If I do need to, how can I avoid this for the future?

Thanks!

```
Battery Information:

  Model Information:
  Serial Number:    C0153670BW1F90MA9
  Manufacturer: DP
  Device Name:  bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:    0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 511
  Hardware Revision:    000a
  Cell Revision:    1200
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   6103
  Fully Charged:    Yes
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   6280
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  401
  Condition:    Replace Now
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    0
  Voltage (mV): 8460

System Power Settings:

  AC Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 60
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   10
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    60
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  Wake on LAN:  Yes
  AutoPowerOff Delay:   14400
  AutoPowerOff Enabled: 1
  Current Power Source: Yes
  DarkWakeBackgroundTasks:  1
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep:   0
  Standby Delay:    10800
  Standby Enabled:  1
  Battery Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 15
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   10
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    15
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  AutoPowerOff Delay:   14400
  AutoPowerOff Enabled: 1
  DarkWakeBackgroundTasks:  0
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  Reduce Brightness:    Yes
  Standby Delay:    10800
  Standby Enabled:  1

Hardware Configuration:

  UPS Installed:    No

AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  ID:   0x07a1
  Wattage (W):  45
  Family:   0x00ba
  Serial Number:    0x008475d0
  Charging: No
```

[image: coconuts]

Comment: Regardless of what coconutBattery says I would think your battery is toast. It could be something else but tat is my first guess. Take it in for repair. An Apple store or other local repair shop that you can trust.

Answer (score 2):

I found this article 'About Mac notebook batteries' on Apple's website, click on the link to go to the article: [About Mac notebook batteries](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204054)

In the report you submitted (in the first block) I read this:

> Condition: Replace Now

That's probably not good, and I think you'll have to replace the battery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to replace it. I would definitely take it to an Apple Store or other Apple-authorised Repair Shop. A new battery for $130 will make your MBA 'as good as new', and restore its useful life for another 4 years.

At the very least, you could sell it on eBay, making a feature of the brand new battery.

Batteries can and do fail, and there's often no predicting it or trying to avoid it with behaviour.